# Where can I find a Gerudo Shield that always respawns?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I need a Gerudo shield because I keep breaking the Daybreaker. I have been searching for over 2 months, and I can't find a Gerudo shield anywhere.

Does anybody know a place in Hyrule where the Gerudo Shield can respawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be one in Gerudo Town somewhere. There is definitely one on top of a stone spire east of Dako Tah Shrine, guarded by a few camouflaged Lizalfos. The Lizalfos themselves everywhere around Gerudo Town often carry them, also.

Source: https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Gerudo_Shield